# How can I click on drawn points and make a external window opening?

Tags: c#

I want to click on points that I drew.

It would be also cool if a window would popup and I could do something with that. But the general thing i want to do is **clicking on a drawn point**. I want to make it work, that i can click on the map on points that I drew.

Example image:

[image]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Graphics g;
        Pen p;
        Point cursor;


        int k = 0;
        Point[] points = new Point[50];
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            g = pbxkarte.CreateGraphics();
            p = new Pen(Color.DeepSkyBlue, 3);


        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void Pbxkarte_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           if (drawmodecbx.Checked == true)
            {

                g.DrawEllipse(p, cursor.X - 10, cursor.Y - 10, 20, 20);
                points[k++] = new Point(cursor.X, cursor.Y);
                lbxDrawnPoints.Items.Add("X:" + cursor.X + "Y:" + cursor.Y);


            }
        }

        private void Pbxkarte_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            cursor = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
            xydisplay.Text = "X:" + cursor.X + "Y:" + cursor.Y;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is extremely unclear. You need to better explain what you are trying to accomplish and provide code that is self-dependent and relevant to the question.

Comment: I inserted a picture above, please click on the link to make it visible.

Comment: The code above is responsible for drawing the points, that u can see in the picture(link)

Comment: `g = pbxkarte.CreateGraphics();`  Don't do this.  Use the paint event of the container to get the graphic object.  If you know where you are painting your points, you can use the same logic to compare where the mouse is clicking: loop through your points.

Comment: If you want to know when a mousemove is over one of the points you can convert each to a GraphicsPath and use its [IsVisible(point)](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.isvisible?view=netframework-4.8) method. - Also: Do avoid arrays for List<T>, here List<Point> and best also a List<GraphicsPath>. Lists a extensible and generally much more versatile.

Comment: Also: You can use the MouseClick event and avoid the cursor variable. And you can Use e.Graphics.FillPath(gp) in the pbox Paint event for correct, persistent drawing..

Comment: @LarsTech How can I draw with the paint event? It would be very kind if you have some code for me to use the Paintevent. (I would like to draw circles)

Comment: This is incredibly easy to research.  We can help you, but you have to do some of the grunt work.

Comment: @LarsTech It would be very nice if you could help me. I made a lot of research, but didn't find the right solution for me.

Comment: Use the paint event of Pbxkarte, loop through your points: `foreach (Point p in points) { e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, New Rectangle(p.X - 10, p.Y - 10, 20, 20);}`  Avoid cursor, instead use the MouseDown event to either create your point, using `e.Location`, or determine if you are clicking on one of those points.

Comment: @LarsTech Hello! I just tested the code that u wrote me and I recognized that it draws a point only on a specific point. I want the user later to draw random points and these randomly placed points need to be clickable. Sry that I first didn't write it that clear what I want

Comment: Move your `if (drawmodecbx.Checked)` into the MouseDown code to determine if you are making a point, or clicking on a point.  As mentioned by someone else, use a `List<Point>` instead of an array to make your life easier when adding points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example code:

Two class level variables and a helper function:

```
List<Point> dots = new List<Point>();
int dotSize = 12;

Rectangle fromPoint(Point pt, int size)
{
    return new Rectangle(pt.X - size/ 2, pt.Y - size / 2, size, size);
}
```

The mouseclick (as opposed to the click event) contains the location:

```
private void Pbxkarte_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (!dots.Contains(e.Location))
    {
        dots.Add(e.Location);
        Pbxkarte.Invalidate();  // show the dots
    }
}
```

You could add code to remove dots or change the properties, esp. if you create a dot class. - If you want to avoid overlapping dots you can to use code like the one in the mousemove to detect this. But. Don't repeat the code! Instead factor out a `boolOrPoint IsDotAt(Point)` function you can use both times!!

In the mousemove I only show the hit state. You do your thing..

```
private void Pbxkarte_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    bool hit = false;
    foreach (var dot in dots)
    {
        using (GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath())
        {
            gp.AddEllipse(fromPoint(dot, dotSize));
            if (gp.IsVisible(e.Location))
            {
                hit = true; break;
            }
        }
    }
    Cursor = hit ? Cursors.Hand : Cursors.Default;

}
```

All dot in the list must get shown every time anything changes, both in the list or in the system.:

```
private void Pbxkarte_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var dot in dots)
    {
        using (GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath())
        {
            gp.AddEllipse(fromPoint(dot, dotSize));
            e.Graphics.FillPath(Brushes.Red, gp);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want more properties, like texts or colors do create a `class dot` and use a `List<dot>` !

Comment: It would be very kind if you could look at my recent question. It's very important and I think you could have an idea.